# How to split a dictionary in a Pyspark dataframe into multiple rows?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe that is extracted with the following command:

```
extract   = data.select('properties.id', 'flags')


|   id  | flags                      |
|-------| ---------------------------|
| v_001 | "{"93":true,"83":true}"    |
| v_002 | "{"45":true,"76":true}"    |
```

The desired result I want is:

```
|   id  | flags |
|-------| ------|
| v_001 | 93    |
| v_001 | 83    |
| v_002 | 45    |
| v_002 | 76    |
```

I tried to apply `explode` as the following:

```
extract   = data.select('properties.id', explode(col('flags')))
```

But I encountered the following:

```
 cannot resolve 'explode(flags)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not struct<93:boolean,83:boolean,45:boolean,76:boolean>
```

This makes sense as the schema of the column is not compatible with the `explode` function. How can I adjust the function to get my desired result? Is there a better way to solve this problem?

P.D.: The desired table schema is not the best design but this is out of my scope since this will involve another topic discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might already looked, `explode` requires `ArrayType` and it seems you are only taking the keys from the dict in `flags`.

So, you can first convert the `flags` to `MapType` and use `map_keys` to extract all keys into list.

```
df.withColumn('flags', F.map_keys(F.from_json('flags', MapType(StringType(), BooleanType()))))
```

This will result in like this

```
+-----+--------+
|   id|   flags|
+-----+--------+
|v_001|[93, 83]|
|v_002|[45, 76]|
+-----+--------+
```

Then you can use `explode` on the `flags`.

```
.select('id', F.explode('flags'))
```

```
+-----+---+
|   id|col|
+-----+---+
|v_001| 93|
|v_001| 83|
|v_002| 45|
|v_002| 76|
+-----+---+
```

The whole code

```
df = (df.withColumn('flags', F.map_keys(F.from_json('flags', MapType(StringType(), BooleanType()))))
      .select('id', F.explode('flags')))
```

**Update**

It is probably better to supply the schema and read as `MapType` for the flags but if your json is complex and hard to create the schema, you can convert the `struct` into `String` once then convert to `MapType`.

```
# Add this line before `from_json`
df = df.select('id', F.to_json('flags').alias('flags'))

# Or you can do in 1 shot.
df = (df.withColumn('flags', F.map_keys(F.from_json(F.to_json('flags'), MapType(StringType(), BooleanType()))))
      .select('id', F.explode('flags')))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I encountered a new problem: `cannot resolve 'entries' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, 'flags' is of struct<93:boolean,83:boolean,45:boolean,76:boolean> type.;`

Comment: oh sorry I missed it. looks like your flags is `struct` not `string`.  How are you reading data to the dataframe (schema inferred or are you supplying schema)?

Comment: No need to apologize, I am glad you are helping me :) It is schema inferred. I am reading a file with `data=spark.read.json(json_file)`, then I tried to select the id and use `explode` for the flags...

Comment: updated. please check it out and see if this works